EF Core 8 - Use model with multiples parents and cascade delete
I use .NET Core 8 & EF Core 8 (i also use AutoMapper but i think this is not relevant for now)
I have the following classes:
public class MainA {
    public string Prop1 { get; set; }
    public string Prop2 { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<ChildA> ChildsA { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<ChildB> ChildsB { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<ChildC> ChildsC { get; set; }
}


public class ChildA {
    public string Prop1 { get; set; }
    public string Prop2 { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<SubChildA> Childs1 { get; set; }
}

public class SubChildA {
    public string Prop1 { get; set; }
    public string Prop2 { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<SuperChild> Childs1 { get; set; }
}

public class ChildB {
    public string Prop1 { get; set; }
    public string Prop2 { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<SuperChild> Childs1 { get; set; }
}

public class ChildC {
    public string Prop1 { get; set; }
    public string Prop2 { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<SuperChild> Childs1 { get; set; }
}

public class SuperChild {
    public string Prop1 { get; set; }
    public string Prop2 { get; set; }
}

With the "Owns..." Configrations it seems archiveable.
But i also need to query all SuperChilds at once.
With the Owns-Stuff this isn't posible because i then always have go over all the other tables also.
With the normal relation configuration i have multiple FK's on SuperChild thats also bad because i want a DeletionCascade. If MainA is deleted all related data should also be deleted.
Then there is the possibility to generate some "Link"-Models like:
public class ChildB {
    public string Prop1 { get; set; }
    public string Prop2 { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<ChildB_Link_SuperChild> Childs1 { get; set; }
}


public class ChildB_Link_SuperChild
{
    public Guid ChildBId { get; set; }
    public virtual ChildB ChildB { get; set; }

    public Guid SuperChildId { get; set; }
    public virtual SuperChild SuperChild { get; set; }
}

public class ChildB_Link_SuperChildConfiguration : IEntityTypeConfiguration<ChildB_Link_SuperChild>
{
    public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<ChildB_Link_SuperChild> builder)
    {
        builder.HasKey(rd => new { rd.ChildBId, rd.SuperChildId });

        builder.HasOne(x => x.ChildB )
            .WithMany(x => x.Childs1)
            .HasForeignKey(x => x.ChildBId)
            .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Cascade);
    
        builder.HasOne(x => x.SuperChild)
            .WithOne()
            .HasForeignKey<ChildB_Link_SuperChild>(x => x.SuperChildId)
            .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Cascade);
    }
}

But then the FK is on the Link-Model means the Link-Model will be deleted if ChildA or ChildAA will be deleted. But not the ChildAA remains in database if the Linking-Model is deleted.
So i am completly out of ideas.
I think i have to go with Own-Configuration and make some crazy Concat-Call to archive that.
Concat call example:
db.Set<MainA>()
    .SelectMany(x =>
        x.ChildsA.SelectMany(y => y.Childs1).SelectMany(z => z.Childs1)
            .Concat(x.ChildsB.SelectMany(y => y.Childs1))
            .Concat(x.ChildsC.SelectMany(y => y.Childs1))
    )
    .ToList();

Do you think this is the best solution?
Do you have any other ideas to archive that?
Do you think the Concat statement is translateable and has a good performance?

Update: The approche working with Concat to get all SuperChilds isn't working with EF Core

Why is not working? Which error?

you have to delete child first then you can delete the parent so you can use range for child deletion inside  a   transaction  after successfully transaction commit the transaction

you have to do it for each level  other wise your code will be break on a certain level

the way you are selecting the children you can also use include for this purpose

Also you can use lazy loading for  load your child for that  you have to install the package    Microsoft proxies
and configure only your moduleBuiler like this
protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
    => optionsBuilder
        .UseLazyLoadingProxies()
        .UseSqlServer(myConnectionString);
    }

and make you Navigation Properties virtual
if you do not want that so you can use union because union return only distinct record for you.
Union is better than concat
db.Set<MainA>()
            .Where(ma => ma.Id == Id)
            .SelectMany(ma => ma.ChildsA.SelectMany(ca => ca.Childs1)
                                .Union(ma.ChildsB.SelectMany(cb => cb.Childs1))
                                .Union(ma.ChildsC.SelectMany(cc => cc.Childs1)))
            .ToList();

you can configure you parent and child entity like that so when you delete parent it will delete child automatically.
builder
    .Entity<Parent>()
    .HasMany(x => x.Child)
    .WithOne(x => x.Child)
    .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Cascade); 

builder
    .Entity<Child1>()
    .HasMany(x => x.SuChild)
    .WithOne(x => x.SubChild)
    .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Cascade); 

you can also mention your foreign key property using data annotation in  your entity class.
OR
if you have nullable f_keys so you have to use set Null option is good because it is just possible there are two foreign key presents in single entity so deletion may be causing data loss.
    builder
        .Entity<Child1>()
        .HasMany(x => x.SuChild)
        .WithOne(x => x.SubChild)
        .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.SetNull); 

Otherwise if you want  delete the child must Then you have to  got all the child and then delete them. for this the good approach is to use the Efcore transactions.

That isn't working when you want to use the Child in different Parents. Because then you need to allow the ForeignKey to be nullable. And this will break the DeleteCascade

but in your entities optional relation isn't mentioned

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/saving/cascade-delete

here you can see  there is no cacade cycle for  optional relations
